# php- compressing a base64 decoded image fails

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-compression

I get images as base64 encoded string front end and I have to decode them and save them as images in server. Image can be of any format- png,gif or jpeg.
This part works fine. But sometimes the images uploaded by the users can be of very large size, so I'm trying to compress them from backend and this part failed miserably.

I have two functions. One for converting base64 string to image and other one for compressing it.

This is the function that converts the string to an image.

```
function uploadTimelineImage($base64Img)
{
    $data= array(); 
    $upAt=date('YmdHis');

    if (strpos($base64Img, 'data:image/png;base64') !== false) 
    {
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64Img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);    
        $extension= 'png';
    }

    if (strpos($base64Img, 'data:image/gif;base64') !== false) 
    {
        $img = str_replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '', $base64Img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);    
        $extension= 'gif'; 
    }

    if (strpos($base64Img, 'data:image/jpeg;base64') !== false) 
    {
        $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $base64Img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);    
        $extension= 'jpeg'; 
    }

    $fileName     = 'img'.$upAt.$extension;
    $filePath     = 'foldername/'.'img'.$upAt.$extension;

    //upload image to folder
    $success = file_put_contents($filePath, $data);
    $result  = $success ? 1 : 0;

    //call to compression function
    $compressThisImg= $filePath;
    $d = compress($compressThisImg, $fileName, 80);

    if($result==1)
    {
        return $fileName;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is the function that does compressing:

```
//Function to compress an image
function compress($source, $destination, $quality) 
{
    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

    return $destination;
}
```

But the above function does not do any compression, it throws error:

```
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

and my function uploads the original image.

Comment: A general remark: trying to compress images of an already compressed format (png, gif, jpg) does not make any sense.

Comment: If the image is that large, maybe your system's `.ini` files need to be adjusted in order to handle bigger files. If the larger files do get uploaded though, then you can scratch this comment. Something else is causing this and I can't see what it is. However, check the path settings and permissions.

Comment: It will reduce the size anyway and yeah, I know I will lose clarity as well. Is there anyway to reduce the size of the image from the backend. As far as I know, base64 converts an image to string, it doesnot reduce size. i checked the original file and the uploaded file. @arkascha

Comment: It's not about uploading larger images, I'm trying to compress them a little bit so they will get loaded a little bit fast. @Fred -ii-

Comment: The *failed to open stream: No such file or directory* error to me, tells me that the compressed image isn't being saved (and/or read) correctly; that's what I get from this. @AmeliaEarheart

Comment: No! Compressing an already compressed image will _not_ reduce its size! At least not above a trivial level. So it makes no sense. And it would _not_ reduce sharpness, you got that wrong. There are different types of compression. You'd have to decompress it again anyway on the receiving side, otherwise you do not have an image, but a compressed file.

Comment: I'd sure like to know where/how `$destination` is assigned to. Again: `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` to me, most likely has something to do with this. I see you're in the answer below. I really hope that will solve the issue here.

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is, compress the image and upload it but that didn't work well..so I was trying to upload the image first (that part worked well), then compress the image and replace the uploaded image with the compressed image. But compression didn't work. So, destination is same as the image path @Fred -ii-

Comment: Ah, I see now; thanks for the clarification. I hope the answer works for you then :-) @AmeliaEarheart *fingers crossed*

Comment: Haha....Thank you sooo much  @Fred -ii-

Comment: @AmeliaEarheart You're welcome. However, that answer not working for you? I haven't seen it as being accepted or any other comments in there.

Comment: Sounds like a path problem to me. Can you post the full text of the error ? You can also troubleshoot the problem using this checklist : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use this function for create any type of image form base64 edncoded image string?

```
function uploadTimelineImage($base64Img,$h,$w)
{
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($base64Img);
    if ($im !== false) {


        $width = imagesx($im);
        $height = imagesy($im);
        $r = $width / $height; // ratio of image

        // calculating new size for maintain ratio of image
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r; 
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }

        $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        imagecopyresampled($dst, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        imagedestroy($im);

        $fileName  = 'img'.date('Ymd').'.jpeg';
        $filepath =  'folder/'.$fileName  ;
        imagejpeg($dst,$filepath);

        imagedestroy($dst);
        return $fileName;
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it reduce the size of an image? @Haresh Vidja

Comment: you want to reduce image size or quality of image?

Comment: Image size mostly..I don't care if I lose a little bit of clarity as well. But image size mostly. @Haresh Vidja

Comment: @AmeliaEarheart, I have modified code for image resize with custom height ane width passing in function.

Comment: Thanks dear..i'll try this code. Hope this will fix the problem. @Haresh Vidja

Comment: Glade to hear from your side dear @AmeliaEarheart, let me know if need anything from my side.